# Openpyxl compare subsequent rows in column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, cell

I've been learning Python for the express purpose of creating a program that automates part of my job. I'm far along in the learning process to feel comfortable to take on a small part of the problem.

I want to create a function that combines two cells into one, with just one of their values (meaning I don't want to concatenate), if they are equal to each other. If they aren't it will pass.

I don't know how to express this in a for loop. I really want to complete this project myself, but I need some jumping off point. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've created a virtual environment and have the following code. I understanding indexing with for loops for lists, but don't know how it works with openpyxl. Again, I am very new to programming in general, but am excited to work on this problem. The issue I have now that I haven't been able to find online, is how do I refer to cell's location and then have it refer to subsequent cell's location.

from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb  = workbook()

ws = wb.active

#load existing spreadsheet

wb = load_workbook('input.xlsx')

column_i = ws['I']

def same_name()
for cell in column_i:
if cell.value[cell] == cell.value[cell+1]

Comment: Your question is too vague. Can you show how looks like your Excel spreadsheet and/or give a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: for each cell in column, if cell.value == subsequent_cell.value, merge cells and only return the value of cell 1

Comment: Got you, see the answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iter_cols`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter%20cols#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols) to loop through each column then use [`merge_cells`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=merge_cells#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.merge_cells) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def merge_subsequently(inpath, outpath):
    wb = load_workbook(inpath)
    ws = wb.active
    
    for col in ws.iter_cols():
        for _1st, _2nd in zip(col, col[1:]):
            if _1st.value == _2nd.value:
                ws.merge_cells(None, _1st.row, _1st.column,
                                     _2nd.row, _2nd.column)
    
    wb.save(outpath)

p1 = "/Desktop/input.xlsx"
p2 = "/Desktop/output.xlsx"

merge_subsequently(p1, p2)
```

*BEFORE :*

[image]

*AFTER :*

[image]